# How to integrate Matlab producing dll with .net?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, .net-framework-version

I am trying to integrate Matlab producing dll with my .net project when I call make its object it gives the below error.

**Error 1   Could not load file or assembly 'ChordRecognizerDotNETAssemplyForTuning' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.**

I have installed MCR and frameworks till 4.0 as you can see in pic. please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in your main projects app.config file

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` should do the trick.

And don't forget to set your target framework to ".NET Framework 4" rather than ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

Comment: no ... it does not work. i put it in configuration tag in Web.Config and check the target too in properties but no success.